# Load JSON objects using value from Angular UI datepicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I want to load JSON objects only if the date property of the objects `event.node.date` matches the date selected by the user from the Angular UI datepicker `ng-model="dt"`. I'd be grateful for any help.

Here's my stuff as it stands, loading **all** the JSON objects regardless of date and with the datepicker not actually connected to the get request in any way:

JS:

```
var weekEventsController = function($scope, $http){
   $http.get('/json/next7days').success(function(result){
      $scope.weekEvents = (function(){
         return result.nodes;
      })();
   });  
   $scope.today = function() {
       $scope.dt = new Date();
   };
   $scope.today();
   $scope.clear = function () {
       $scope.dt = null;
   };
   $scope.open = function($event) {
       $event.preventDefault();
       $event.stopPropagation();
       $scope.opened = true;
   };
   $scope.dateOptions = {
       formatYear: 'yy',
       startingDay: 1
   };
   $scope.format = 'dd MMMM yyyy';
};
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8"  ng-controller="weekEventsController">

    <h2 datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min-date="{{today}}" max-date="'2016-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close">
        {{dt | date:'dd MMMM yyyy' }} 
        <i class="fa fa-calendar-o" ng-click="open($event)"></i>
    </h2>

    <div class="mainEventItem" ng-repeat="event in weekEvents"> 
        <main-item-container>
                <div class="mainItemDetails">
                   <h2 class="eventTitle">{{event.node.title}}</h2>
                   <p class="eventDate">{{event.node.date | date: 'EEEE'}} / {{event.node.field_time}} / {{event.node.venue}}</p>
               </div>
        </main-item-container>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: How to go about this depends mostly on your backend, but in a similar case I found it useful to post the date to the backend with something like `$http.post('/json/next7days', $scope.dt)`. If you ensure your $scope.dt is actually a Date object (which it should be in your case) angular will convert it to an Iso8601 string for processing by your backend.

Comment: Thanks @Fasermaler, that sounds sensible. I think I'm going to try filtering after they've loaded as I'm not sure I can post back.